# How to declare a Query/Service in Akita in order to use it in another module

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-akita, akita

I'm starting to use Akita in my ionic application.

I've a `SessionModule`, in which I declare a `SessionService`, `SessionQuery`, ...
But I would like to listen to the SessionQuery in my `app.component.ts`.

I tried to declare everything in my `SessionModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SessionQuery } from './store/session.query';
import { SessionService } from './store/session.service';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SessionQuery,
    SessionService
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports:[
    SessionQuery,
    SessionService
  ]
})
export class SessionModule { }
```

I declared it as `import` in my `app.module.ts`

And use it in my App.Component.ts:

```
 public name$ = this.sessionQuery.selectName$;

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private sessionQuery: SessionQuery
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }
```

but when I run it, I get some errors:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'SessionQuery' declared by the module 'SessionModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
Unexpected value 'SessionService' declared by the module 'SessionModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

What should I do? Is it mandatory to use a query only in the same module where it's declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

In fact, you do not need to import/export anything, BUT, you need to mark service+store+query injectable by placing this before each class declaration:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```